# MailKit + .NET Core "Sender address rejected: not owned by user" error

Tags: c#, .net-core, mailkit

I have this MailKit implementation in a .NET Core 3.1 API with C# as the language

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;

public static void sendMail()
{
   var mailMessage = new MimeMessage();
   mailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("myAddress@company.com", "myAddress@company.com"));
   mailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("targetAccount@company.com", "targetAccount@company.com"));
   mailMessage.Subject = "Test Subject";
   mailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
   {
      Text = "Test Body"
   };

   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
   client.Connect("smtp.company.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
   client.Authenticate("myAddress@company.com", "ThePasswordWhichIWillEncryptAfterTesting");
   client.Send(mailMessage);
   client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

As you might have already guessed, it doesn't work, the error message thrown is:
**SmtpCommandException: 4.7.1 <myAddress@company.com/>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user myAddress@company.com**

I have no idea what's going on and there's virtually no documentation on the internet either, only the same error message in different platforms where the fix does not apply to my case, I also tried putting the actual user names instead of a copy of the mail in the "MailboxAddress" function first argument

I used this article for reference: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/

Thanks

Comment: does the webconfig/app json mail settings username match your from address?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, here's the json for reference:
"SmtpSettings": {
    "Server": "smtp.company.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "SenderName": "Company Mail System",
    "SenderEmail": "myAddress@company.com",
    "UserName": "myAddress@company.com",
    "Password": "ThePasswordWhichIWillEncryptAfterTesting"
 }

Comment: It *may* be valuable to get a protocol log (see https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog for details) and then verify the `MAIL FROM` command. Does it have that `/` in it? That should not be there.

Comment: No, sorry the "/" was added so the "<>" could be shown in the question

Comment: according to the log*, the `MAIL FROM` command is the same as myAddress@company.com, the error message is the same that the application was throwing me

Comment: That's really strange. Seems like maybe a bug with the SMTP server?